# "over five people" or "more than five people"?

Tags: grammar

> There were over five people in the class.
>
> There were more than five people in the class.

I know for sure that the second sentence is correct. But I am in doubt as for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one time your first example ("over five people") would have been considered a mistake. There used to be a distinction - "over" being used for non-count or mass things - over five tons of coal, over ten gallons of water, and "more than" for countable things - more than ten people, more than 20 cars. Many style guides now say that they are interchangeable.

[More than vs. over](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/more-than-vs-over-a-big-change-at-the-associated-press)